# Custom Menu item on right click of Controllers folder in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, mvcextensions

Can I add a custom menu item,let say "Add xxx Controller" to right click menu when user click on Controllers folder in MVC application.

Regards,
Patil